# how to update Parent field when old records already existed in child through process builder

Tags: process-builder

parent field should be update from child with already existed records. with out "created or edited" in process builder.

ex: claim -- field name "cost" should be updated from its child "claim line item" . for old records.

can anyone suggest me ways, if we cant through process builder.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? This sounds like something an admin would typically achieve through Data Loader.

Comment: child field (claim line item) is having multiple old records. these record values must show in parent field (cost).   i have created a rollup summary and created a process builder to show what ever changes we do. and its working .  but, my problem is, its not updating old records(around 2500 records). if i do any changes , its taking as update and its working......so,  how can i make them all records to update through any process.                                                                           
                                                               thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a Rollup Summary Field, it is not clear why a Process is required. Please [edit] this post to include all of this information, and please be as clear as possible about your data model.